# How can i replace 1 material with another material on one specific object?

Tags: texturing, materials

I am seeing many guides for how to replace materials on multiple objects with "material 1"with "material 2" but i want to be able to do that on just 1 object, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Select the object you want to change. Go to the Material Properties tab (1). There you will see the name of the material which is currently on the object (2) and a number beside the name of the material (3). This is the number of objects which are using the same material. Click the New Material icon (4) and the name will change to xxx.001 showing that it's now a seperate material.

[image]

You can then change the colour to whatever you want without affecting any of the other objects as shown below. (I've also changed the colour name to a more appropriate name.)

[image]